# Rails 5 google-places gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places

I installed ['google_places' gem](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places) on rails 5 but could not get it to work.When I run this code snippet:

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(Rails.application.secrets.places_api_key)
```

It gives such an error:

```
 uninitialized constant PlacesController::GooglePlaces
```

And my controller:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end

  # GET /places/nearbies
  # GET /places/nearbies.json
  def nearbies
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(Rails.application.secrets.places_api_key)
    @places = @client.spots(-33.8670522, 151.1957362)
  end

  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /places/new
  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  # GET /places/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /places
  # POST /places.json
  def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /places/1
  # PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.update(place_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /places/1
  # DELETE /places/1.json
  def destroy
    @place.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to places_url, notice: 'Place was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_place
      @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:title, :address, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
end
```

I did not solve it, I appreciate your help.

EDIT:

Its my fault. I accidentally built the [google-places gem](https://github.com/OmkarPatil2510/google-places)

Comment: Just to check. Did you add `gem 'google_places'` to Gemfile' and run `bundle install` command?

Comment: Yes i did. The gem looks a bit old, can it be related to it?

Comment: I've tried to install it on my Rails 5 project and it's working well. Did you try it in rails console? Sure, you've reloaded a server after.

Comment: When I try with the console I get the same result again.Yes I restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

Need to do this

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  require 'google-places'
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end
```

Comment: Where exactly do I add the require definition in the controller?

Comment: below class PlacesController < ApplicationController

Comment: I updated my question and added it to my controller codes, would you tell me what to do by looking there?